# can vuetify's selects component support query function?

Tags: vuetify.js

i had read all api about selects components's api.seems like there not a prop support quert function from itemlist

there is a prop  named 'filter',but i don't know how to use it

```
 <v-select
          v-model="activity.scs"
          :items="statement"
          item-text="name"
          item-value="id"
          label="Select"
          persistent-hint
          return-object
          multiple
          chips
          deletable-chips
          clearable
          counter
          filter
          >
</v-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to query the select search results by using filter property

Use like this:

> In select component add filter property

```
<v-select
          v-model="activity.scs"
          :items="statement"
          item-text="name"
          item-value="id"
          label="Select"
          persistent-hint
          :filter="selectFilter"
          return-object
          multiple
          chips
          deletable-chips
          clearable
          counter
          filter
          >
</v-select>
```

> in methods

```
selectFilter(item, queryText) {   
  queryText = queryText.toLowerCase();

  return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryText) > -1 || item.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryText) > -1; 
}
```

This way you can have custom filters to search on all the properties in your item object